# Format decimal in shell command

Tags: linux, shell

Input

```
  CTCF_1276       4.006055058150985e-03
  CTCF_1274       1.726979566495019e-02
```

Output

```
  CTCF_1276       4.00606e-03
  CTCF_1274       1.72698e-02
```

I know `awk` can do this very easily, but I don't like it because I need to escape the `%.5e` in the string if I want to call it from python. Does anyone have better way to do this?

Comment: Why is one truncated and the other rounded up when both should be rounded up?

Comment: If you're in Python, you can surely do this within Python?  I simply don't believe it's necessary to shell out to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- bash:

  ```
  printf '%.5e' 4.006055058150985e-03
  ```
- python:

  ```
  print('{:.5e}'.format(4.006055058150985e-03))
  ```
- perl:

  ```
  printf '%.5e', 4.006055058150985e-03
  ```
- awk:

  ```
  printf '%.5e', 4.006055058150985e-03
  ```

Comment: Doesn't python have a `%` operator for strings that does formatting? `print "%.5e" % ( 4.006055058150985e-03 )` would make it a lot more conformant with the others.

Comment: @tadman - Yes, it is refered to as [_old string formatting_](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) in python documentation and is excpected to be removed from the language.

Comment: Breaking with tradition? That link indicates it's *not* supposed to be deprecated, though.